# Rounded corners and shading issues

Tags: modeling

Here's what i am trying to do: a beveled cube, inside of it a rectangular hole with rounded corners. First i made a cube with the hole, then added a plane with beveled vertices for the rounded corners; merged both and bridged the edge loops and added a edge split modifier. It worked, but there are still shading issues from certain angles. Is there a better way to do this?

[image]

Edit: .blend-file: [image]

Comment: Please upload your blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and I will make an answer.

Comment: Great thanks, tell me also what is the purpose of this mesh? Is this gonna be game asset, realistic rendering or something else?

Comment: possibly some kind of vending machine, low-poly asset for game-engine use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method:

Add a Plane and scale on the "X" axis to form your rectangle.

[image]

TAB into Edit Mode and add four Loop Cuts (CTRL + R) positioned where you want your hole to be.

[image]

Select all by pressing "A". Extrude by pressing "E" + "Z" to constrain on the z axis.

[image]

Scale in by pressing "S" + SHIFT "Z" to constrain to the x and y axis.

Select the inner top face and press "X" and "Only Faces" from the drop down menu to delete it.

[image]

Add a Subdivision Surface Modifier (View and Render set to two.

[image]

Tab into Object Mode and set shading to Smooth. Tab back into Edit Mode and add Loop cuts to tighten up you corners.

[image]

Repeat for all your corners.

[image]

### [image]

---

Comment: thanks, the shading is much better that way. The only downside is, that the subsurf modifier requires way more extra geometry (edge loops) to refine the corners.